# My point cloud orientation is very wrong

Tags: cesium

I'm trying to load a cloud point using Cesium and Entwine.

This is my code until now:

First I convert a LAS file to EPT using [this](https://entwine.io/quickstart.html) tutorial but [need to convert](https://entwine.io/configuration.html#cesium) projection to `EPSG:4978`.

`entwine build -i https://data.entwine.io/red-rocks.laz -o ~/entwine/red-rocks-ept -r EPSG:4978`

Now I have an EPT folder. Lets [convert it](https://entwine.io/configuration.html#cesium) to Cesium 3D tiles:

`entwine convert -i ~/entwine/red-rocks-ept -o ~/entwine/red-rocks`

Now I have a folder with Cesium files.

Lets serve them. I'll use docker but any http server will do it well. Don't forget to allow CORS:

`docker run -it -v ~/entwine/cesium:/var/www -p 8080:8080 \
    connormanning/http-server`

Now in Cesium:

```
var tileset = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
     url : 'http://YOUR_SERVER:8080/red-rocks/tileset.json',
}));    


tileset.readyPromise.then(function(tileset) {
    camera.viewBoundingSphere(tileset.boundingSphere, new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(0, -0.5, 0));
    camera.lookAtTransform(Cesium.Matrix4.IDENTITY);        
});
```

My cloud is floating or lost somewhere in space:

[image]

Anything I do with mouse (change the camera view) the cloud disapear forever.

Already tried to remove the `readyPromise` event.

**Can't find the ENTWINE tag.**